# How to find that 'runas' execution finished?

Tags: ruby, windows, windows-7, cmd, runas

I use `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]` on Windows7. Recently I upgraded from Windows XP where I didn't have to run commands as administrator so I wasn't facing such issue.

To do mySQL backup I run `runas /savecred /user:yogurt\administrator "cmd.exe /k mysqldump --user=#{dbuser} --password=#{dbpassword} #{dbname} > #{dump}"` - mysqldump must be executed as administrator. I do not run my ruby scripts under administrator account.

runas starts new cmd.exe and ruby doesn't wait for it to finish. Dump process takes about one minute to finish. After that I zip the dump file and delete it.

But I have to make sure that the dump process already finished before I do any other action on that file. Right now I use `sleep(60)` that works but I wonder if there any better more systematic solution.

## update - ruby code

```
dump="c:\\dbdump.sql"
cmd="runas /savecred /user:yogurt\\administrator \"cmd.exe /c mysqldump --user=root --password=password tafdb413 > #{dump}\""
output = %x[#{cmd} 2>&1]
puts "flow continues even though dump hasn't finished yet :-("
      sleep(130)  
cmd="runas /savecred /user:yogurt\\administrator \"cmd.exe /c del #{dump}\""
output = %x[#{cmd} 2>&1]
```

### update2

I was thinking that I can create a file after the dump finishes as a second command inside cmd.exe. ruby will be checking for the existence of the file every second or so.

Comment: What does the ruby code you're using to call this look like? I suspect this will end up being more about Windows than about ruby, but seeing the ruby code will make sure.

Comment: @dpassage: I agree with you but I think that ruby needs to take care of this in this case.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to just run `mysqldump` instead of shelling it out into `cmd`?

Comment: `runas` runs it new shell anyway so it really doesn't matter.